# How to convert 7e0acdbf6a527e to 0x7e 0x0a 0xcd 0xbf format and store in array in python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert 7e0acdbf6a527e to 0x7e 0x0a 0xcd 0xbf in python, can some one help me?

Comment: Are you talking about the hexadecimal strings or actual byte sequences?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`grouper` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) to get the pairs of characters:

```
from itertools import izip_longest # or zip_longest in Python 3.x

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args) # see comment above
```

Then [string `join`ing and `format`ting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```
hexes = ["0x{0}".format("".join(t)) for t in grouper(s, 2)]
```

This gives me:

```
>>> s="7e0acdbf6a527e"
>>> hexes = ["0x{0}".format("".join(t)) for t in grouper(s, 2)]
>>> hexes
['0x7e', '0x0a', '0xcd', '0xbf', '0x6a', '0x52', '0x7e']
```

You can also [convert to `int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) from this:

```
>>> [int(s, 16) for s in hexes]
[126, 10, 205, 191, 106, 82, 126]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is a string, you can do this:

```
data = "7e0acdbf6a527e"
mod = zip(data[::2], data[1::2])
result = ['0x{}'.format(''.join(item)) for item in mod]
['0x7e', '0x0a', '0xcd', '0xbf', '0x6a', '0x52', '0x7e']
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what you *really* want.

```
>>> s = "7e0acdbf6a527e"
>>> ['0x' + s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
['0x7e', '0x0a', '0xcd', '0xbf', '0x6a', '0x52', '0x7e']
```

To deal with them as actual integers:

```
>>> s = "7e0acdbf6a527e"
>>> result = ['0x' + s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
>>> print [int(x, 16) for x in result]
[126, 10, 205, 191, 106, 82, 126]
```

Answer (score 0):

Two more simple variants to go from hexadecimal string to number sequence:

```
>>> string = '7e0acdbf6a527e'
>>> import binascii, array
>>> a=array.array('B', binascii.a2b_hex(string))
>>> a
array('B', [126, 10, 205, 191, 106, 82, 126])
>>> map(hex,a)
['0x7e', '0xa', '0xcd', '0xbf', '0x6a', '0x52', '0x7e']
>>> a=[int(string[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0,len(string),2)]
>>> a
[126, 10, 205, 191, 106, 82, 126]
```

But the question is lacking context (such as what you're trying to do or what data types the values have or should have).

Answer (score -1):

```
string = '7e0acdbf6a527e'

answer = ['0x{0}'.format(string[ii-1:ii+1]) for ii in xrange(1,len(string)+1,2)]
```